# Enumerating value across a foreign key relationship in MVC?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

My database has a variety of different tables that reference each other through the use of standard fk relationships. I'm trying to figure out how to setup my controller and views to display the contents of these other tables/models from within the main view.

I apologize if it's a bit confusing, but here's an example. I have a table `employees` and I'm attempting to list all the emails for that employee in my detail view, the emails are stored in `email_manager` and there is a foreign key that references the `employee_id` column from the `employees` table. My `employee` model looks something like this:

```
[Table("employee.employees")]
public partial class employees1
{
    public employees1()
    {
        employee_email_manager = new HashSet<email_manager>();
        employee_employment_history = new HashSet<employment_history>();
        employee_job_manager = new HashSet<job_manager>();
        employee_phone_manager = new HashSet<phone_manager>();
        this.salaries = new HashSet<salary>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int employee_id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Employee ID")]
    public int? assigned_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Web User ID")]
    public int? all_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name="First Name")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name="Last Name")]
    public string last_name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Display(Name="Birthday")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime birth_day { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    [Display(Name="Gender")]
    public string gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    [Display(Name="Social")]
    public string social { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    [Display(Name="Address")]
    public string address_line_1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name="Suite/Apt#")]
    public string address_line_2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    [Display(Name="City")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name="State")]
    public string state { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(11)]
    [Display(Name="Zip")]
    public string zip { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Display(Name="Hire Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime hire_date { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Display(Name="Separation Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? termination_date { get; set; }

    [StringLength(70)]
    [Display(Name="Emergency Contact Name")]
    public string emergency_contact_name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    [Display(Name = "Emergency Contact Number")]
    public string emergency_contact_phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Notes")]
    public string notes { get; set; }

    public virtual all_employees all_employees { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<email_manager> employee_email_manager { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<employment_history> employee_employment_history { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<job_manager> employee_job_manager { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<phone_manager> employee_phone_manager { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<salary> salaries { get; set; }
```

And my `email_manager` model is:

```
    [Table("employee.email_manager")]
    public partial class email_manager
    {
        [Key]
        public int email_id { get; set; }

        public int employee_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string email { get; set; }

        public int email_type { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime date_added { get; set; }

        public bool deleted { get; set; }

        public virtual email_types email_types { get; set; }

        public virtual employees1 employees1 { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("employee.email_types")]
    public partial class email_types
    {
        public email_types()
        {
            email_manager = new HashSet<email_manager>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int email_type_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string email_type_name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<email_manager> email_manager { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving this one was actually an all day task for me, but I managed to finally crack the answer. It turns out that even though my foreign keys were mapped inside the the ApplicationDbContext, they weren't being mapped properly. This was causing me some serious headache, and it turns out it was heavily related to another question I asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349798/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-invalid-column-name-phone-types-phone-type).

To remedy this, I had to explicitly define my foreign key columns within each of my respective models, using `[ForeignKey("FOREIGN_KEY_COLUMN")]` directly above my collection housing the model with the respective primary key. The corrected version is similar to:

```
    [Table("employee.email_manager")]
    public partial class email_manager
    {
        [Key]
        public int email_id { get; set; }

        public int employee_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string email { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("email_type")]
        public int email_type { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime date_added { get; set; }

        public bool deleted { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("email_type")]
        public virtual email_types email_types { get; set; }

        public virtual employees1 employees1 { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("employee.email_types")]
    public partial class email_types
    {
        public email_types()
        {
            email_manager = new HashSet<email_manager>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int email_type_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string email_type_name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<email_manager> email_manager { get; set; }
    }
```

Within the view, to reference the appropriate emails, you can then do something similar to:

```
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employee_email_manager)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @foreach (var item in Model.employee_email_manager)
        {
            <text>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email_types.email_type_name): </text>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
            <br />
        }
    </dd>
```

This change didn't require changing my employees1 model in any way, only the referenced models such as `email_manager`, `phone_manager`, etc.