# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'UserId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserId'

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have migrated the ASP.NET Membership provider to ASP.NET Identity, Post Migration when I am trying to create user (with duplicate username) using Web Api Controller I get the following error. This error is not catch on IdentityResult.

> "message": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid
>   column name 'UserId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserId'.\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.b__24(Task1
>   result)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()\r\n
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()\r\n--- End of stack trace
>   from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter1.GetResult()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.d__c.MoveNext()\r\nClientConnectionId:95d07c45-7f78-448c-9392-09999eb8c42d"

My Code.

```
var user1 = new ApplicationUser
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        UserName = ud.Username,
                        Email = ud.Email,
                        IsApproved = false,
                        ApplicationId = new Guid("4600317a-8e7e-476a-86f1-8409a5ed60b7"),
                        LoweredUserName = ud.Username.ToLower(),
                        LastActivityDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1754-01-01 00:00:00.0000000"),
                        CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                        IsLockedOut = false,
                        LoweredEmail = ud.Email.ToLower(),
                        LastLoginDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1754-01-01 00:00:00.0000000")
                    };
var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user1, ud.Password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Backend of your Entity Code. It could be, that after the migration it took the old connection strings with.

Here is a link to an old same problem: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349798/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-invalid-column-name-phone-types-phone-type)