# invalid column name after when I added new field for model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

when I added new fields to my model(Memy) I have a error that :

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Invalid column name 'kategoria'.
Invalid column name 'opis'.
Invalid column name 'title'.
Invalid column name 'img'.
Invalid column name 'modifyDate'.
Invalid column name 'relaseDate'
```

my model Memy:

I tried a few things but they didn't help:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/new-field?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio
- https://dzone.com/articles/steps-to-add-new-field-with-code-first-approach-in
- [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'phone_types_phone_type_id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349798/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-invalid-column-name-phone-types-phone-type)

I added a migration then update-database but this didn't work ,I do not know what I am doing wrong?

```
public partial class Memy
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int IdMema { get; set; }
        public string Autor { get; set; }
        [Required]
       public string Title { get; set; }
        public string coverImg { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
       public  string Category { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public DateTime? releaseDate { get; set; }
         public DateTime? modifyDate { get; set; }
        public int? Like { get; set; }
        public int? Dislike { get; set; }
    }
```

model memyContext

```
public partial class memyContext : DbContext
    {
        public memyContext()
        {
        }

        public memyContext(DbContextOptions<memyContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public  DbSet<Memy> Memy { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Memy>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.IdMema);

                entity.Property(e => e.IdMema)
                    .HasColumnName("Id_mema")
                    .ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.Autor)
                    .HasColumnName("autor")
                    .HasColumnType("text");
                entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                  .HasColumnName("title")
                  .HasColumnType("text");
                entity.Property(e => e.releaseDate)
                 .HasColumnName("relaseDate")
                 .HasColumnType("date");
                entity.Property(e => e.modifyDate)
                 .HasColumnName("modifyDate")
                 .HasColumnType("date");
                entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                 .HasColumnName("opis")
                 .HasColumnType("text");
                entity.Property(e => e.coverImg)
                 .HasColumnName("img");
                entity.Property(e => e.Category)
                 .HasColumnName("kategoria")
                 .HasColumnType("text");

                entity.Property(e => e.Dislike).HasColumnName("dislike");

                entity.Property(e => e.Like).HasColumnName("like");

            });
        }


       // public DbSet<MemeGenerator.Models.Mems> Mems { get; set; }


       // public DbSet<MemeGenerator.Models.AppSettings> AppSettings { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Did you add the migration and then updated your database?

Comment: Did you dropped your database with `Drop-Database`? It's nescassary because when you update your `Context` by, in this case, changing the columnnames, the database hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: Yeah,First I drop-database,then add-migration and the end update-database and that error is...