# Asp.net C# MVC Need a Model/ViewModel which can provide same view (same table) and link to two different fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have already gone to all and evert possible recommendations of similar questions a well as other google search. But nothing is working.
May be since I am new to MVC.

My issue is I have a Invoice_Master which as two fields Billing_To_ID and Supplying_To_ID.
Both are coming from one Billing_To_Master.

Now in Invoice_Master View, I want to incorporate same. But tried so many options from search, but none is getting fulfilled. Instead two different fields like Billing_To_ID, Project_ID from two different models is working fine.

I have following codes done till now:-
model Billing_To_Master

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ACBooks.Models
{
    public class Billing_To_Master
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Display(Name = "Billing To ID")]
        public decimal Billing_To_ID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Billing To")]
        public string Billing_To_Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "State")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Pincode")]
        public string Pincode { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ARN")]
        public string ARN { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "GST")]
        public string GST { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "PAN")]
        public string PAN { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "SAC")]
        public string SAC { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Contact Name")]
        public string Contact_Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Mobile")]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Landline")]
        public string Landline { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Flag ID")]
        public bool Billing_To_Flag_ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

model Invoice_Master

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ACBooks.Models
{
    public class Invoice_Master
    {


        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Display(Name = "Invoice_ID")]
        public decimal Invoice_ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Invoice Type")]
        public decimal Invoice_Type_ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Invoice Type Name")]
        public virtual Invoice_Type_Master Invoice_Type_Master_Obj { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Invoice No")]
        public string Invoice_No { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Invoice Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Invoice_Date { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Billing To")]
        public decimal Billing_To_ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Billing To Name")]
        public virtual Billing_To_Master Billing_To_Master_Obj { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Supplying To")]
        public decimal Supplying_To_ID { get; set; }

        //Trying this - but not working
        [Display(Name = "Supplying To")]
        public virtual Billing_To_Master Supplying_To_Master_Obj { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Client Code")]
        public string Vendor_Code { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Field Work Center")]
        public string Fieldwork_Center { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Field Work Dates")]
        public string Fieldwork_Dates { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Kind Attention")]
        public string Kind_Attn { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Invoice Subject")]
        public string Invoice_Subject { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Project ID")]
        public decimal Project_ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
        public virtual Project_Master Project_Master_obj { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category ID")]
        public decimal Category_ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
        public virtual Category_Master Category_Master_obj { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Brand ID")]
        public decimal Brand_ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Brand Name")]
        public virtual Brand_Master Brand_Master_obj { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Town")]
        public string Town { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tax Code")]
        public string Tax_Code { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Reference")]
        public string Reference { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and this is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<ACBooks.Models.Invoice_Master>

    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Invoice_Type_Master_Obj.Invoice_Type_Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Invoice_No)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Invoice_Date)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Billing_To_Master_Obj.Billing_To_Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Supplying_To_Master_Obj.Billing_To_Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vendor_Code)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fieldwork_Center)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fieldwork_Dates)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Kind_Attn)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Invoice_Subject)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Project_Master_obj.Project_Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category_Master_obj.Category_Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Brand_Master_obj.Brand_Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Town)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tax_Code)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reference)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Invoice_Type_Master_Obj.Invoice_Type_Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Invoice_No)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Invoice_Date)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Billing_To_Master_Obj.Billing_To_Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Supplying_To_Master_Obj.Billing_To_Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vendor_Code)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fieldwork_Center)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fieldwork_Dates)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Kind_Attn)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Invoice_Subject)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project_Master_obj.Project_Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category_Master_obj.Category_Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Brand_Master_obj.Brand_Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Town)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tax_Code)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reference)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Invoice_ID })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Invoice_ID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Any resolution for same would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use Billing_To_Id as foreign key in invoice_master.

If in case, you are unable to use foreign key due to business constraint, you can use ViewModel and send that ViewModel to view like below.

```
public class BillingViewModel
{
    //You can use List<T> if you need to
    public Billing_To_Master BillingToMaster { get; set; }

    public Invoice_Master InvoiceMaster { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion on foreign key helped me a lot.
Just refer to my answer posted. If you edit your answe and can have some same more detailed resolution, I would love to accept your answer.

Comment: @YeshwantMudholkar Yes, this is the way to go. If there are no business constraints & its sql then you should definitely create relationships. Apart from this I would suggest to refactor your properties names. See this example: Class Product does not require "ProductId" as its property instead it should be only "Id". Reason readability and consistency across the code structure. So what is easy to read: Product.ProductId or Product.Id

Answer (score 0):

As per Jayesh Tanna's answer, I went into detail for foreign key. I deleted all relations first. And assigned foreign keys again.
[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23368161/10289226) helped me further to trace the answer.

After using the [ForeignKey(<*ID*>] and the issue was resolved.

```
    [Display(Name = "Billing Name")]
    [ForeignKey("Billing_To_ID")]
    public virtual Billing_To_Master Billing_To_Master_Obj { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Supplying ID")]
    public decimal Supplying_To_ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Supplying Name")]

    [ForeignKey("Supplying_To_ID")]
    public virtual Billing_To_Master Supplying_To_Master_Obj { get; set; }
```